# Where is the Magic in the Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

In my RazorView i use:

```
@Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
```

to get the EditorForm. It also creates the Tags: `data-val-*` with Validationmessages. But in this auto generated Validationmessages the variablename is shown as type.

```
data-val-number="The field &quot;Int32&quot; must be numeric."
```

I think this is because the object that cames to the Validationfunction misses the variablename and so he uses the type. So I need to know where the function tries to get the variablenname or which field the function tries to read to fix this.

p.s.
I realy don´t want to change my previous code to fix this, it has his reasons why it is like it is ;-)

Comment: By default a Razor view would not output a validation message for a INT32 filed jsut from @Html.Editor() do you have a @Html.ValidationMessageFor.  Plus I would suggest changing the name of your post its not very well worded.

Answer (score 1):

The variable name will default to the Property name unless you add a `[DisplayName("New Name")]` attribute to the Property to change the name used. What type is `prop` in your example?

Comment: `@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => Html.ShouldShow(pm)))`